# How to provide a @ControllerAdvice conditional on bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm creating a framework that I'd like to reuse in all of my future projects. If the sub project does not define a `@ControllerAdvice`, I want my framework to automatically initialize a default Advice for exception handling.

```
public class ExHandler implements IAdvice {
    ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorDTO default(xception e) {
        return new ErrorDTO();
    }
}
```

I tried as follows, but does not work:

```
@Configuration
static class MyConfig {
    @ControllerAdvice
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(IAdvice.class)
    static class AdviceExHandler extends ExHandler {

    }
}
```

In Sub project:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SubHandler extends ExHandler {
}
```

Result: It works. BUT: if the subproject does not define the `ExHandler`, the bean is not initialized at all! But why?

Sidenote: I'm trying to prevent mutliple `ControllerAdvice` because error handling depends on the order of methods inside the exception handler. Thus I don't want to mess the order by introducing multiple classes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use @ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = ControllerAdvice.class) to configure condition on missing bean with ControllerAdvice annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public abstract class FrameworkAdvice {
...
}
```

And conditionally configure it:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = ControllerAdvice.class)
public class FrameworkAdviceConfig {
    @Bean
    public FrameworkAdvice frameworkAdvice() {
        return new FrameworkAdvice() {
        };
    }
}
```

And if there is another controller advice in project, it will be used instead.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomAdvice {
...
}
```

Comment: Wow, great. Did not know about the ability to define conditions based on annotations. That fits perfectly.

Comment: Maybe FrameworkAdviceConfig is unnecessary becase once FrameworkAdvice class is anotated it will always be wired in by Spring. Further more if there is another class in the project annotated with @ControllerAdvice it might cause conflict.

Comment: @Pastx The config is necessary because `FrameworkAdvice` is `abstract`. If it weren't, granted, maybe the `FrameworkAdviceConfig` would not be necessary *if* 
 that `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` works on `@ControllerAdvice` classes, which I don't know if they do (haven't tested).

Answer (score 4):

You could use it without wrappers. Just declare `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class as following in Kotlin:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = [ControllerAdvice::class])
class ExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler
    fun handleProcessingException(e: Exception): ErrorDto {
        return ErrorDto()
    }
}
```

And just declare it in `spring.factories` file if you're doing it for starter:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  ru.raiffeisen.ecommerce.controller.ExceptionHandler
```

That's all. If there is no `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes, then will be used class from configuration.